# How to fix "System.ArgumentNullException" in iOS?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

Im working on an app that was given to us by another group within our university. I am using Xamarin to make a cross platform app that we picked up from last years group. They made no progress with the iOS side of things and it is working fine on android.

I am working on the iOS and and running into some problems with the first page. It has a button that takes you to a list view but when I press it the error

```
System.ArgumentNullException has been thrown
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: sourceFileName
```

comes up.

I have tried looking for the parameter name but there is no file called sourceFileName.

This is in the main.cs -

```
public class Application
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        class from "AppDelegate"
        UIApplication.Main(args, null, "AppDelegate");
        //This is where the error pops up ^
    }
}
```

This is the appdelegate file -

[Register("AppDelegate")]
public partial class AppDelegate : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate
{

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
    global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
    LoadApplication(new App());

    return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
}
```

}

This is the code for the button -

```
private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new SelectCancerType());
        }
```

SelectCancerType -

```
public partial class SelectCancerType : ContentPage
    {
        private string Cancer { get; set; }
        public SelectCancerType()
        {
            NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = new SelectCancerTypeViewMode();
        }
        private async void Button_Back_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string page = "cancer";
            // handle the tap  
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new Helps(page));
        }

        private async void Button_Next_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Cancer = CancerTypeList.SelectedItem.ToString();
                await Navigation.PushAsync(new Treatments(Cancer));
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Error", "Please select an option", "OK");
            }

        }
```

Code for SelectCancerTypeViewMode -

```
public class SelectCancerTypeViewMode :BaseViewModel
    {      
        public List<string> Cancers { get; set; }
        public SelectCancerTypeViewMode()
        {
            Cancers = App.Database.GetCancers();
        }
    }
```

Full Stacktrace -

System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: sourceFileName
  at System.IO.File.Copy (System.String sourceFileName, System.String destFileName, System.Boolean overwrite) [0x00003] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.2.1.16/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/File.cs:77
  at System.IO.File.Copy (System.String sourceFileName, System.String destFileName) [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.2.1.16/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/File.cs:69
  at CanRehab.iOS.FileAccessHelper.CopyDatabaseIfNotExists (System.String dbPath) [0x00016] in /Users/Isaac/Projects/stechr8/CanRehab.git/CanRehab/CanRehab/CanRehab.iOS/FileAccessHelper.cs:27
  at CanRehab.iOS.FileAccessHelper.GetLocalFilePath (System.String fileName) [0x00010] in /Users/Isaac/Projects/stechr8/CanRehab.git/CanRehab/CanRehab/CanRehab.iOS/FileAccessHelper.cs:19
  at CanRehab.iOS.FileLocation.GetDBLocation (System.String filePath) [0x00001] in /Users/Isaac/Projects/stechr8/CanRehab.git/CanRehab/CanRehab/CanRehab.iOS/FileLocation.cs:19
  at CanRehab.App.get_Database () [0x00001] in /Users/Isaac/Projects/stechr8/CanRehab.git/CanRehab/CanRehab/CanRehab/App.xaml.cs:28
  at CanRehab.ViewModels.SelectCancerTypeViewMode..ctor () [0x00008] in /Users/Isaac/Projects/stechr8/CanRehab.git/CanRehab/CanRehab/CanRehab/ViewModels/SelectCancerTypeViewMode.cs:19
  at CanRehab.Views.SelectCancerType..ctor () [0x00017] in /Users/Isaac/Projects/stechr8/CanRehab.git/CanRehab/CanRehab/CanRehab/Views/SelectCancerType.xaml.cs:23
  at CanRehab.MainPage+d__1.MoveNext () [0x0000f] in /Users/Isaac/Projects/stechr8/CanRehab.git/CanRehab/CanRehab/CanRehab/MainPage.xaml.cs:22
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+<>c.b__6_0 (System.Object state) [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.2.1.16/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/AsyncMethodBuilder.cs:1023
  at Foundation.NSAsyncSynchronizationContextDispatcher.Apply () [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.2.1.16/src/Xamarin.iOS/Foundation/NSAction.cs:178
  at at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain(int,string[],intptr,intptr)
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.IntPtr principal, System.IntPtr delegate) [0x00005] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.2.1.16/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:79
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x0002c] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.2.1.16/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:63
  at CanRehab.iOS.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00001] in /Users/Isaac/Projects/stechr8/CanRehab.git/CanRehab/CanRehab/CanRehab.iOS/Main.cs:18

Comment: if the exception is thrown when you click a button, then you should start by looking at the code that handles the button click

Comment: Share the code that handles button click event.

Comment: I have edited the question to show the button, your help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you please share the code of SelectCancerType?

Comment: The select cancer type has now been added. thank you

Comment: The problem might be in `SelectCancerTypeViewMode`. Can you post the full stack trace of the exception?

Comment: Add the code of SelectCancerTypeViewMode and stack trace may help. There is no problem with the code you post so far.

Comment: The SelectCancerTypeViewMode and the stack trace has been added, Cheers

Comment: Add the code of GetCancers please. I guess the problem happens when you get data.  And always add all relevant codes . Are u using [File.copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.copy?view=netframework-4.7.2)?